# hide delete button in list page in dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am using Asp.Net Dynamic Data. I want to remove delete button from List and details page. I dont want to remove it from mark up. Is there any way to remove delete button based on entity and without adding custom pages?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was able to do it with this code.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton delete = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("DeleteLinkButton");
            delete.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey kane sorry for that format. I have again tried it but the editor is not giving output as i want. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating a custom page and you will have all control over default pages template. Look following video explains how to do it.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-dynamic-data/how-do-i-make-custom-pages